# Post to Facebook multiple photos with status message in single wall post

Tags: ios, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble posting like this image. A common caption for all images & multiple images. At least, tell me if it is **possible or not** ?

[image]

I have tried to loop through all images & succeed to post all images as shown in the image but not getting the caption. (In image it's : "TEST: PLEASE IGNORE FRNDS."). How can i do it ?

My code is posting successfully but the problem is that each photo is a different post. I want all photos in one single post.

Here's what i tried:

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfImages = [self getSelectedImagesArray];
    for (int i=0; i<arrayOfImages.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setObject:@"LOL !! THIS IS IMAGE" forKey:@"message"];
        //[params setObject:@"LOL !! APP NAME" forKey:@"name"];
        [params setObject:@"LOL !! THIS IS IMAGE CAPTION" forKey:@"caption"];
        [params setObject:@"LOL !! THIS IS IMAGE description" forKey:@"description"];
        [params setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i], 0.5) forKey:@"picture"];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error)
         {
             NSString *alertText;

             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure
                 [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
                  {
                      [self shareAdvertOnFacebook];
                  }];
                 alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"error: domain = %@, code = %d", error.domain, error.code];
             }
             else
             {
                 //showing an alert for success
                 alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted action, id: %@", result[@"id"]];
                 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Advert is posted to Facebook successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
             }
         }];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have publish_stream permission to create a new album.
Then to create a new album, make a Graph API call to https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums with parameters for the access token, the album name, and the album description.

If the album is created successfully the new album ID will be returned.
Then make a call to https://graph.facebook.com/NEW_ALBUM_ID/photos with the access token and other photo parameters to upload your photo to the new album.

By default, if you do not specify any album and just push photos to the me/photos endpoint your photos will end up in an album automatically created for your application.

**This code worked for me, just you have to add your code to "post all images"**

```
- (void) postImageToFB:(UIImage*)image
    {
        NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
        NSString *text=@"Purchased a book From Library Store,\nBook Name-";
        text=[text stringByAppendingString:lbl_bk_name.text];
        text=[text stringByAppendingString:@"\nCategory-"];
        text=[text stringByAppendingString:lbl_bk_category.text];
        text=[text stringByAppendingString:@"\nFeeling Great!!"];


        NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        text, @"message",
                                        imageData, @"source",
                                        nil];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {


                                  if (error) {
                                      UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Problem in sharing in Facebook. Try Later!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                      [alert show];
                                  } else {


                                          UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Shared Successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                          [alert show];

                                  }



                              }];
    }
```

Comment: i dont think that you posted multiple images using above code. did you ?

Comment: i have added in code, that  you have to add your code to "post all images"

Comment: My code is posting successfully but the problem is that each photo is a different post. I want all photos in one single post.

Comment: i think u have to use facebook graph api-  Making Multiple Requests
You can chain together publish calls with read calls by using Batch Requests. Please read the guide to Making Multiple API Requests.

Publishing Photos

Photos can be published via Graph API directly to /{user-id}/photos (which will add the photo to a special album created for your app) or to an existing album via /{album-id/photos.                     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41319/discussion-between-akshit-zaveri-and-vizllx)

Comment: Can you please send me the code to upload multiple images via iOS app using Facebook SDK..